# I am getting the error Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, async-await, react-hooks

I am trying to show a progress or loading bar while each answer payload upload to the server and a success message when the whole task is complete? Here is my code but I am getting the error message `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`.

Also note that `getOfflineSavedAnswers` is an imported function hence I can't set it as a function here.

```
export default function UploadReport(type) {
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false) 

    useEffect(() => {
    getOfflineSavedAnswers(type).then(async answers => {
        if (answers && answers.length > 0) {
            try {
                for (const answer of answers) {
                    try {
                        await axios.post('/report/question/create-answer', answer)
                        .then(res => {
                            delAnswers("phcss")
                            setSuccess(true)
                        //  ts(`Answers successfully saved!`);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.error(err);
                            delAnswers("phcss")
                            te(`Answers submission failed!`)
                        });
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                        delAnswers("phcss")
                        te(`Answers submission failed!`)
                    }
                }
                if(success){
                    ts(`Answers successfully submitted!`);
                }
                setSuccess(false)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                te(`Answers submission failed!`)
            }
        }

    });
});
    return(
      success ? 'uploading ans...' : null
    )
};
```

This code is to be called by another class component like below where there are multiple tasks

```
sendReportToServer = () => {
    UploadReport("phc", (msg, error) => {
        if (error) {
            te("Could not upload answer data");
        } else {
            ts(msg);
        }
    })
    UploadAnswer("phc", (msg, error) => {
        if (error) {
            te("Could not upload answer data");
        } else {
            ts(msg);
        }
    })
    UploadQuestion("phc", (msg, error) => {
        if (error) {
            te("Could not upload answer data");
        } else {
            ts(msg);
        }
    })
};
```

Without the hook, when I do `export const uploadReport = async (type) => {` it works just fine. But I introduce the hook because I want to show a progress or loading bar while each answer payload upload to the server and a success message when the whole task is complete

Comment: `UploadReport(type)` seems suspiciously ***not*** like a component function signature. Is `type` the props object? Is `UploadReport` supposed to be a custom hook? If so, rename it to use the `use-` prefix naming convention, i.e. `useUploadReport`.

Comment: @DrewReese why? it renders text or null.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I agree with Drew, typically the argument to a react component, if not destructured, is named props. The argument name in and of itself doesn't matter, but it sure smells like this **might** be called like `UploadReport(type)` instead of `<UploadReport/>`. Good guess from Drew.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because the linter uses very simple rules to determine if a hook is being used validly, and it's not too bright, it simply follows some basic guidelines. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#building-your-own-hooks

Comment: Good spot @DrewReese I didn't notice the lack of props destructuring.

Comment: @DrewReese ```UploadReport(type)``` is supposed to be a function. the *type* is a prop and when it is used by another function the props is supplied like ```UploadReport("phc", (msg, error) => {```

Comment: If type is a prop then it needs destructuring.

Comment: @Wacademy - can you show the code that renders `<UploadReport/>`? If you are simply **calling** `UploadReport(type)` instead of rendering it, that's where the problem is.

Comment: ```
sendReportToServer = () => {
 UploadReport("phc", (msg, error) => {
  if (error) {
   te("Could not upload answer data");
  } else {
   ts(msg);
  }
 })
};
```

Comment: Without the hook, when I do ```export const uploadReport = async (type) => {``` it works just fine. 
But I introduce the hook because I want to show a progress or loading bar while each answer payload upload to the server and a success message when the whole task is complete

Comment: I updated my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Hooks only have meaning when they are used inside React components - i.e. `<MyComponent {...myProps}/>`. They cannot be used (and don't make sense) inside plain JavaScript functions - e.g. `UploadReport('phc',...)`.

Plain JavaScript functions cannot have state, or a lifecycle (no effects).

Just create a regular async function and update state **in the parent** component. You don't need (and can't have) state or an effect in a regular function.

Like this:

```
const MyParentComponent = (props) => {

 const [sending, setSending] = useState(false);

 const handleSendReportToServer = async () => {
    setSending(true);
    await callToSomeAsyncFunctionLikeUploadReport();
    setSending(false);
 }

 return {/* some jsx */}

}
```

Comment: Below code works but how do I show a progress or loading bar in this. I have an imported Progress bar to show when the 3 await tasks is completing. I will like to show the progress bar for each await.The ```UploadReport``` may have up to 100 post request while others may have maximum of 6. I am using the ```handleSendReportToServer``` in a class component.
```
sendReportToServer = async () => {
   this.setState({
    sending: true
   })
   await UploadReport("phcss");
   await UploadAnswers();
   await UploadQuestion();
   this.setState({
    sending: false
   })
  }
 };
```